# Consequences of messing with Timer 0

Tags: timers, attiny85

I'm following this tutorial to generate square waves using the timers of the attiny85, but I'm afraid this could mess with something else in the chip.

This is the relevant snippet:

```
// Set up Timer/Counter0 for 20kHz interrupt to output samples.
TCCR0A = 3<<WGM00;             // Fast PWM
TCCR0B = 1<<WGM02 | 2<<CS00;   // 1/8 prescale
TIMSK = 1<<OCIE0A;             // Enable compare match, disable overflow
OCR0A = 49;                    // Divide by 400
```

I understand that this might affect `delay()`, but as I'm using watchdog timer to send the attiny to sleep, I **think** this in this case it should not affect this specific function.

Are there another negative consequences of modifying this timer?

Comment: so, what is your question? ... the easiest thing would be to write a program that tests timer0 affect on sleep()

Comment: Timer 0 is usually used for millis() and delay().

Comment: I don't see how this could affect sleep. It does affect millis and delay, if you are using a "core" that implement that for the ATTiny85. I think most of them use the overflow interrupt (e.g [ATTinyCore does](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore/blob/778ee472071b434818b7b029461ddc85f13dfb91/avr/cores/tinymodern/wiring.c)). Your code disables that, so as long as you never call delay() or millis() there shouldn't be a problem.